# Which is better, the MB10S or the MB10F?

Tags: temperature, rectifier, thermal, bridge-rectifier

I am replacing a blown MB10 rectifier IC on a small LED power supply. The letter could not be read anymore so I don't know which one to get.  The [S](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/MB10S.pdf) or the [F](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/MB10F.pdf) variant.

In the datasheet the electrical characteristics are identical with the only major difference in package size (which is really negligible) and thermal resistance. Which variant is the superior one?

I would assume it is the F variant since it has a lower thermal resistance of 63 C/W  compared to the 101 C/W of the S variant. It doesn't get quite as hot as the other.

Am I right in choosing the F variant?

Comment: Interestingly the "S" variant lists "Low Leakage Current" under Features and Benefits, which the "F" doesn't. However, the "F" has infact a better leakage specification. It looks better across the board.

Comment: @tobalt i hope there is no nuances to this . Indeed the "F" variant looks to be better. Diodes Incorporated is a good brand so i assume it will last longer this time. The price on the "F" variant is also slightly more expensive so maybe it is indeed the better part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, the two components are almost identical but in terms of thermal resistance the MB10F component is better, having a lower thermal resistance than the MB10S it can dissipate heat better.

If you can't figure out which of the two components you have, you can try to see where the reference mark is located on the device: from the two datasheets you can see that for the MB10F it is between the positive and negative terminals,

[image]

while for the MB10S it is on the side near the positive terminal.

[image]

Comment: Nice catch on the reference mark, i did not notice that. The one that got burnt is the "S" variant, but i went ahead and purchase the F variant, although its more expensive the price is negligible to the amount im buying